# Overwrite folder using s3a.copy

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark

I am using AWS glue job in that
how I can  overwrite a folder content while copying using s3a.copy method in pyspark.
Any way I am able to copy from source to destination folder.
Type of file to copy is parquet.
Also is copy much faster than writing into s3.

I tried s3a.copy in pyspark.
I wanted to overwrite existed file.